# Users of ClickOnce app are redirected from downloading .NET framework 4.6.1 to download 4.6

Tags: c#, clickonce, .net-4.6.1

I just updated app to .net Framework 4.6.1. This app is published with ClickOnce Publish.There is no entry for 4.6.1 in Prerequisites dialogue so I needed to add it [manually](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3119510). I produced these [files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qnkjs4ht0i3jboj/AAC4CEI_ef2wgfXydEk_ckwBa?dl=0). App now calls for installing 4.6.1 framework within update. That is ok.

Problem is, there is fwlink in the Package.xml which leads to desired installator, which is not used. Currently users are redirected to page, where is acknowledged something like "App needs .NET Framework 4.6.1 but we recommends you to download .NET Framework 4.6". There are two links, Framework 4.6 and Framwork 4.6.1, both leading to [.NET Framework 4.6 Web Installer download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48130).

I have no experiences with this sort of stuff. Is possible to change this behaviour? It seems Win OS should propose fwlink from Package file. Or does it compose its own link regarding to any other parameters? Alas, I cannot repro this issue, but it seems Microsoft handle this link and redirects users to wrong page.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was quite simple. Prerequisite settings just didn't refresh. I just selected .NET Framework 4.6 only and then selected back .NET Framework 4.6.1. It seems to be mismatched by sharing this settings via TFS on several computers, when not all of them have modified prerequisite .NET Framework 4.6.1 entry.